# /CLOSED/ Why does it say ECHO is off?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, echo

```
set /a swordparts=1

 If (%swordparts% GTR 0) (
  echo %swordparts%
 )
```

---

it outputs ECHO is off. whats going on here?

I thought it would say 1, as %swordparts% is greater than 0 and equals 1, and when %swordparts% was equal to 0, i was expecting it to not echo anything

Comment: **1.** ```Set "swordparts=1"```, **2.** ```If %swordparts% GTR 0 (```, **3.** ```Echo %swordparts%```, **4.** ```)```.

Comment: Where did you find an example on the internet using parentheses as part of the comparison?

Answer (score 3):

`(%swordparts%` = `(1`

`0)` = `0)`

`(1` is not greater than `0)` so the `echo` will not be executed.

If you are getting any output, it is *not* from the code you posted.

`if` compares whatever is on the the two sides of the operator `GTR`.

Remove the parentheses around the comparison and it *should* work as expected.

---BUT---

If this code is itself within a parenthesised sequence of lines (a `code block`) as I suspect, then you need to beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)